# Flutter merge two Stream<List<Data>> into a single Stream<List<Data>>

Tags: flutter, dart, stream

There's an issue that i hasn't been able to solve, currently i have a

```dart
  Stream<List<SupplyHierarchy>> get suppliesHierarchyFinalLevel => _supplyHierarchyFinalLevelFetcher.stream;
  Stream<List<SupplyHierarchy>> get suppliesHierarchyLevelFour => _supplyHierarchyLevelFourFetcher.stream;

  final _supplyHierarchyLevelFourFetcher = PublishSubject<List<SupplyHierarchy>>();
  final _supplyHierarchyFinalLevelFetcher = PublishSubject<List<SupplyHierarchy>>();

Stream<List<SupplyHierarchy>> getData() {
    return StreamGroup.merge(
        [suppliesHierarchyFinalLevel, suppliesHierarchyLevelFour]);  
}
```

the output that i receive is a List but with only one of the streams.
it do something like this:

```dart
StreamGroup.merge([LIST_WITH_DATA, NULL]);
```

Even when both streams have data loaded.

Any one call guide me about how to solve this issue... thanks.

Comment: but with the combine latest i'll receive a List<List<SupplyHierarchy>> but i need a List<SupplyHierarchy>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dart
import 'package:async/async.dart'; // using v2.5.0

void main() {
  final s1= Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds:1), (count) => count);
  final s2= Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds:2), (count) => 100-count);
  StreamGroup.merge([s1, s2]).listen(print);
}
```

works fine for me, could you provide a minimal code snippet that allows reproducing the error? Your "example" uses a lot of variables not shown, probably that's where you have an error.

Please do not post your entire source code as people sometimes tend to do when asked for a "minimal example".

Comment: Thanks David! Im working on a minimal example, but dartpad doesn't allow for third party libraries (weird), The example that you gave me is good, however the issue is that, on **s1** and *s2*  are both a List, and when i do the merge as you said, i got a List of List

Comment: if I change "(count) => count" to [count, count] and the same with s2, it still works as expected for me.

Comment: My bad... it's seems that i was using Stream.zip and that returns a List of List, with the StreamGroup i thought that it was the same implementation. I try iy with that and works fine :) sorry for the confusion, and thanks for the suggestion/solution.